# How do I make scrollbar semi-transparent?

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview, transparent

I'm developing my first android application using appcompat v7 and the android support library with API 23. I would like to know how can I make the scrollbar semi-transparent like Gmail for example.

This is the scrollbar I get by default on my `RecyclerView`

[my scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx2jx.png)

and this is what I'm trying to achieve

[desired scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAVlY.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom style for your scrollbar. Use `scrollbarThumbVertical`  for providing a custom drawable for the indicator of the scrollbar. Here is a link to a tutorial where you can learn more about styling a scrollbar.[Scroll Bar Styling](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-vertical-scrollbar-styling/)